# Disable BasicAuth fallback

Tags: authentication, servicestack

According to the documentation:
https://docs.servicestack.net/auth/authentication-and-authorization#authenticating-with.net-service-clients

`Although behind-the-scenes it ends up making 2 requests, 1st request sends a normal request which will get rejected with a 401 Unauthorized and if the Server indicates it has the BasicAuthProvider enabled it will resend the request with the HTTP Basic Auth credentials.`

We are using the typescript JsonClient:

https://api.locode.dev/classes/client.JsonServiceClient.html#responseFilter

We are using basic auth but on specific endpoints but do not want to fallback to it. Is there a way to disable this fallback ?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will automatically resend a failed 401 Basic Authenticate which responds with a `WWW-Authenticate` HTTP Response header.

You can override [OnFailedAuthentication()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthProvider.cs#L364) to prevent it from returning a `HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate` in a custom AuthProvider:

```cs
public virtual Task OnFailedAuthentication(IAuthSession session, IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes)
{
    httpRes.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
    httpRes.AddHeader(HttpHeaders.WwwAuthenticate, "{0} realm=\"{1}\"".Fmt(this.Provider, this.AuthRealm));
    return HostContext.AppHost.HandleShortCircuitedErrors(httpReq, httpRes, httpReq.Dto);
}
```